# Is there any code to scan an image and find if it is black?

Tags: php

Is there any codes or scripts , which will scan a jpeg or gif image and find if that image has colors in it or it is black ?

in my site many users upload lots of files , we can extract icons from some jar and nth files , but some will appear black .
So I would like to replace the black icons with file format icon when providing file icon in download page.

Comment: Check out [imagecolorat()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php)

Comment: [php link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorexact.php)

Answer (score 0):

### imagecolorat

> Returns the index of the color of the pixel at the specified location in the image specified by image.
>
> If PHP is compiled against GD library 2.0 or higher and the image is a truecolor image, this function returns the RGB value of that pixel as integer. Use bitshifting and masking to access the distinct red, green and blue component values:

- `image`

  > An image resource, returned by one of the image creation functions, such as imagecreatetruecolor().
- x

  > x-coordinate of the point.
- y

  > y-coordinate of the point.

**Example**:

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng("php.png");
$rgb = imagecolorat($im, 10, 15);
$r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
$g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
$b = $rgb & 0xFF;

var_dump($r, $g, $b);
?>
```

Also, there are others scripts that do this for example [**this one**](http://www.colab-aktiv.com/?page_id=263).